# How to check that a script has not been modified - tried with git attribute ident $Id$

Tags: python, git, sha1

I am maintaining a collection of python scripts that are distributed on several computers. Users might have the fancy idea to modify the scripts so I am looking for an automatic solution to check the script integrity.

I wanted to use git attribute `ident` so that the file contains its own `sha1` and then use `git hash-object` to compare.

It looks like this (.gitattributes contains `*.py ident`):

```py
import subprocess
gitId= '$Id: 98a648abdf1cd8d563c72886a601857c20670013 $' #this sha will be updated automatically at each commit on the file.
gitId=gitId[5:-2]
shaCheck=subprocess.check_output(['git', 'hash-object', __file__]).strip().decode('UTF-8')
if shaCheck != gitId:
    print('file has been corrupted \n {} <> {}'.format(shaCheck, gitId))
# below the actual purpose of the script
```

This is working fine when my script lays inside the git repository but `git hash-object` returns a different sha when outside of my git repository. I guess there is some git filters issue but I do not know how to get around that issue?

Any other painless way to check my file interity is also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the file's hash with the Python module [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html):

```
import hashlib

filename_1 = "./folder1/test_script.py"
with open(filename_1,"rb") as f:
    bytes = f.read() # read entire file as bytes
    readable_hash = hashlib.sha256(bytes).hexdigest();
    print(readable_hash)


filename_2 = "./folder2/test_script.py"
with open(filename_2,"rb") as f:
    bytes = f.read() # read entire file as bytes
    readable_hash = hashlib.sha256(bytes).hexdigest();
    print(readable_hash)
```

Output:

> a0c22dc5d16db10ca0e3d99859ffccb2b4d536b21d6788cfbe2d2cfac60e8117
> a0c22dc5d16db10ca0e3d99859ffccb2b4d536b21d6788cfbe2d2cfac60e8117

Comment: Ok, using this strategy I need a single source of trust somewhere on my network to compare on one side `__file__` with the reference file. However for remote users it may be anoing to always be on the VPN.